# Using a mutex to lock all access to a list object

Tags: c, multithreading, object, winapi, mutex

I want to create some code that will allow the creation of a list that supports operations from multiple threads. My idea is simple: whenever a thread wants to operate on the list it should call `LockList()` and when it finishes it should call `UnlockList()`. By doing this, any other api call to the locked object by another thread will result in a failure and only the owner thread can use the object.

I tested it and surprisingly i have no crashes but instead, after all threads will finish operating on the list, at cleanup `LockList()` fails exactly once and then everything works as expected.

These are the deffinitions of the `LockList()` and `UnlockList()` functions:

```
WINBOOL APIENTRY LockList (HANDLE hList)
{
    #define lpList ((LPLIST_INFO)hList)
    DWORD dwState = WaitForSingleObject(lpList->hMutex, 0);
    if(dwState != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
        return FALSE;

    return TRUE;
    #undef lpList
}

WINBOOL APIENTRY UnlockList (HANDLE hList)
{
    #define lpList ((LPLIST_INFO)hList)
    DWORD dwState = WaitForSingleObject(lpList->hMutex, 0);
    if(dwState != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
        return FALSE;

    ReleaseMutex(lpList->hMutex);
    return TRUE;
    #undef lpList
}
```

I tried testing my code by letting some threads insert items into the list, more specifically i made a list of `Students`. This is the important part of the code:

```
DWORD APIENTRY ThreadProc(LPVOID lpvList)
{
    #define hList ((HANDLE)lpvList)

    for(DWORD I = 0; I < 1000; I++)
    {
        // wait until the thread gets ownership of the mutex ...
        while(!LockList(hList)); 

        // Insert the entity into the list ...

        UnlockList(hList);
    }

    RETURN 0;
    #undef hList
}

#define WORKER_COUNT 40
INT WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hThisInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, INT nCmdShow)
{
    // An anonymous mutex is created with bInitialOwner FALSE
    HANDLE hList = CreateList(GetProcessHeap(), 0, StudentConstructor, StudentDestructor);
    if(hList == NULL)
        return MessageBoxA(HWND_DESKTOP, "Could not create list.", "Runtime Error", MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR);

    HANDLE hThreads[WORKER_COUNT];
    DWORD dwThreadIds[WORKER_COUNT];

    for(DWORD I = 0; I < WORKER_COUNT; I++)
    {
        hThreads[I] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadProc, hList, 0, &dwThreadIds[I]);
        if(hThreads[I] == NULL)
            return MessageBoxA(HWND_DESKTOP, "Could not create worker thread.", "Runtime Error", MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR);
    }

    WaitForMultipleObjects(WORKER_COUNT, hThreads, TRUE, INFINITE);

    for(DWORD I = 0; I < WORKER_COUNT; I++)
        CloseHandle(hThreads[I]);

    while(!LockList(hList))
        printf("Could not get ownership of the list.\n");

    printf("The list has %lu entities.\n", GetListEntityCount(hList));

    if(!DeleteList(hList))
        return MessageBoxA(HWND_DESKTOP, "Could not delete list.", "Runtime Error", MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR);

    return 0;
}
```

It is also worth mentioning that the check done inside all api calls looks like this:

```
// ...
DWORD dwState = WaitForSingleObject(lpList->hMutex, 0);
if(dwState != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
    return FALSE; // or NULL or whatever signals failure.
// ...
```

Am i using `WaitForSingleObject()` correctly? Why does `LockList()` fail once (in main) even though all threads have released ownership of the mutex?

Answer (score 3):

You have unbalanced lock/unlock semantics.

Each call to WaitForSingleObject on a mutex handle needs to be paired with a call to ReleaseMutex (windows mutex objects allow multiple acquisition by the same thread).

Right now if you have LockList(hList); UnlockList(hList);

That translates to:
WaitForSingleObject
WaitForSingleObject
ReleaseMutex

Comment: So how can i check if a mutex is owned/unowned without actually getting ownership to it? This would have actually been a batter question...

Comment: How about `while(ReleaseMutex(lpList->hMutex) == TRUE);` in the `UnlockList()` function? Is that a good practice?

Comment: @Tudor “*how can I check if a mutex is owned/unowned without actually getting ownership to it?*” - you can’t. Not with a Win32 mutex, anyway. There is no API for that. You will have to change your design to simply NOT call `WaitForSingleObject()` in `UnlockList()`. DO NOT call `UnlockList()` unless `LockList()` reports true. And DO NOT call `LockList()` in a busy loop. If you want to wait to gain ownership of the mutex, simply call `WaitForSingleObject()` 1 time with an `INFINITE` timeout.

Comment: @Tudor “*How about `while(ReleaseMutex(lpList->hMutex) == TRUE);` in the `UnlockList()` function? Is that a good practice?*” - absolutely not. That is horrible practice, and will introduce more problems.

Comment: The usual answer is to only unlock when you know you have ownership. That your LockList would in fact wait until the thread is able to lock the mutex. I.E the following sequence: WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE); /* locked operations */ ReleaseMutex(hMutex);